# Shortcode to show the (child)categories a post belongs to (1 post)

Tags: wordpress, categories, shortcode

I'm looking for a shortcode to add in a post in order to show the categories a post belongs to.

An example. I have a category 'region' with some subcategories :

Region

- region A
- region B
- region C

I would like to add a shortcode in my posts that shows the subcategories of 'Region'.

Again an example :

> This activity is possible in
>   [shortcode-to-show-the-childcategories-of-region].

Hope to find some help here.

Thanks in advance!!